# Is "just a date without time" really a valid concept in the light of internationalization?

Tags: datetime, internationalization, timezone, jodatime, nodatime

I always had conceptual troubles with date values being represented as objects without time (SQL for instance has the type `DATE` beside `DATETIME`). The same thinking often creates issues in languages that always store dates along with a time (e.g. C#'s `DateTime`). Suddenly timezone bugs pop up and the developers insist that all that timezone hullabaloo can be ignored, because their `DateTime` is actually "just a date". But what does that even mean?

The way I see it, such a "plain date" can be interpreted in only two ways:

1. From the perspective of points in time (i.e. "instants") one might infer that "2019-09-17" means the start (end) of the day, which is "2019-09-17 00:00:00" ("2019-09-17 23:59:59"). Hence timezone information is relevant and we are not talking about "just a date".
2. The other option is that the date is supposed to mean the whole day, so we are actually talking about a *timespan* from "2019-09-17 00:00:00" to "2019-09-17 23:59:59" and timezone information cannot be ignored either.

I argue that all use cases for "plain dates" fall in either of the two categories and that time/timezone can only be ignored if the software will only run on and communicate with systems configured with the exact same timezone.

Can someone provide a counter example or a third interpretation?

Comment: There's a long time interval during which some parts of the earth consider "the current time" as part of a given date — it's about 49 hours in total, from when 2020-01-01 (for example) starts at 2020-01-01T00:00:00+13:00 to when it stops at 2020-01-01T23:59:59-12:00.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "holiday" is an example of a date without a time, and even without a time zone.

Most holidays are religious in nature, and I don't want to start a religious war, or get sidetracked by minutiae.  So as an example holiday, I'm going to pick Earth Day:  April 22 of each year in the civil calendar.

If you write software that deals with holidays, said software isn't necessarily dealing with an instant in time across the entire planet (though it could do that in addition to tracking holidays).  Instead it carries the concept that maps April 22 of each year to Earth Day.  And it is irrelevant that some people will celebrate Earth Day hours before or after other people.

If a client wants to know exactly when Earth Day starts/ends for him, then he can translate "the date" into specific instants of time using his particular time zone.  The need for that translation does not diminish the value of the date (say 2020-04-22).

C++20 will have several types to represent a "timezone-less date" such as 2020-04-22 using different data structures:

```
local_days         // day 18374                   == April/22/2020
year_month_day     // year 2020, month 4, day 22  == April/22/2020
year_month_weekday // year 2020, month 4, 4th Wed == April/22/2020
```

Comment: Although I'm a martian and feel slightly offended, this is still a good example. Thank you for the explanation. I now understand the need for dates w/o time/timezone. However, do you think it is valid to argue that this is a special case and in many instances the time component of a date should not be ignored?

Comment: My apologies.  Planet Day it is. :-)  I run a calendar company.  I need software to print out my calendars, and we ship them all over the world.  I specialize in the civil calendar, and my software can localize names of months and weekdays.  My software also uses dates, which have no associated time-of-day or timezone.  The dates just need to know things like basic date arithmetic, and what their year, month, and day values are.

Comment: Great examples, Howard. :)  Another one: A person's birthday.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, I was also considering the birthday example, but I think it doesn't apply. Of course, there is a useful simplification involved such that people usually don't care about the time of birth, which leads to the general consensus that birthdays last the whole day on which one was born. But consider a software that awards discounts on birthdays. Should it deny customers the discount, because they are in a different timezone than the server? If not then the server must interpret the birthday as a timezoned date with the implicit start/end time 00:00/23:59.

Comment: birthday == holiday

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride https://codeofmatt.com/handling-birthdays-and-other-anniversaries/

Comment: Howard Hinnant, sorry, but I don't understand how this equivalence helps with the birthday discount problem (when client and server are in different timezones such that it's the clients birthday only for the client, but not for the server). Can you please elaborate?
@MattJohnson-Pint, I see how this blog post explains how to properly check age restrictions (for example), but I don't see the connection to the birthday discount problem.

Comment: I don't think it is worthwhile to dive into details of the birthday discount problem.  In such a scenario it is easy to think of rules that both involve time zones and rules that don't.  If you're looking for more examples where a zone-less date would be useful, I can supply more.  Conversions between calendars.  Mortgage computations.  Predicted future dates based on the gestational periods of celebrity mammals.  Prison release dates.  Hotel reservations.  Counting business days.  When is hunting season.  Interactive history exhibits.  Historical climate averages.  Book publishing date.

Comment: Well, I guess the truth of the matter is, there is no real generalization possible when it comes to dates, times, and timezones. It always depends on the specific use case. What a horrible software development problem ^_^ Anyway, thank you for your patience!